# Fade class in when 'clicked 'Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey I'm trying to fade my 'Text' class in using JQuery - when I use the 'click' event. I've managed to do it but It comes in instantly, rather than fading in after 1.5 secs, where am I going wrong?

So display is set to none in the CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".top-left").click(function() {
    $(this).css("height", "70vh");
    $("#about").css("top", "-20px");
    $("#about").css("transition", "1s");
    $('.text').delay('15000').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the HTML too. Also, if you're setting the animation using a CSS transition, the JS code would seem to be a little redundant.

Comment: delay() just work with animate functions (fades, slides, toggles)

Comment: Use this $('.text').fadeIn(1500); insteaded of delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the "display" property in CSS to "block". it should be set to "none" if you want your text to fade.

try this instead:

```
$('.text')
  .delay(15000)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
    next(); 
  });
```

delay() works with the animation (fx) queue. Changing a css property does not work via that mechanism so, is not affected by the delay directive.

You can use "hide" as well. 
example:

```
$('.text')
      .delay(15000)
      .queue( function(next){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
        next(); 
      });
```